# Result of calling performSelector: on a "sleeping" thread's current run loop?

Tags: ios, multithreading

I asked myself a question, but have no answer yet so I hope you could have one:

What happened if there is a `NSThread` having his current `NSRunLoop`(named `runLoop1` for example) in "sleeping" state (well, `runLoop1` called `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:/*...*/]`) while an other `NSThread` is calling `[self performSelector:@selector(selector:) onThread:runLoop1 withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]`?

I hope I'm understandable ^^

Comment: The `sleepForTimeInterval` completely blocks the that thread. As [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/thread/1413673-sleep) says, "No run loop processing occurs while the thread is blocked." For this reason, you rarely ever want to `sleepForTimeInterval` in production code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runloop can be explained as an infinite loop:

```
while(!exit) {
   // Do stuff here
}
```

This runs on a thread and if this thread is in sleep then so is the loop and no events will be called on it.

So then what are `performSelector` methods:

Imagine there is an array of invocations with that loop which will be executed when appropriate. Since there is a method to perform the selector after a delay there is also a time stamp.

```
while(!exit) {
   NSMutableArray *notExecuted = [NSMutableArray new];
   for(Executable *item in [self.pendingExecutables copy]) {
      if(item.executionDate && [item.executionDate compare:[NSDate date]] == NSOrderedDescending) {
          [notExecuted addObject:item];
      } 
      else {
           [item execute];
      }
   }
   self.pendingExecutables = notExecuted;
}
```

So calling `performSelector` really does nothing but adds the data needed to perform it into some array. The runloop must be running for the execution to actually happen. So in your case nothing happens, the selector will not be performed because the loop is not executing since the whole thread is sleeping.

You can then also understand what happens if you block the main thread. No touch events, no system notifications, no nothing. It is all just kept in array and it will be called once the thread is unblocked and another loop occurs. The main loop also sends the date on each cycle which is then used for the watch dog. Since the OS works on another thread then your application it is the OS that will check that date and if it is relatively old you get to "application not responding" state. And then the OS may decide to kill your application.

Note that this is oversimplified but it is enough to get a basic understanding on how these things work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What happened to the event skipped during the destination thread sleep? Are they  processed when the thread awake or just ignored?

Comment: They should be processed once the thread awakes as long as the thread has the run loop. There might be a way for it to be skipped if the calling thread is the same as the one that will be executing. Do you have a case where that happened?

Comment: Not especially, but because I'm working with these objects, I was wondering.

Comment: Well it is possible to mess up but it depends on what you are doing. I would try to avoid sleep if possible. But in general it should work, just be careful what you are calling from which thread.